# How to reuse a Collection View? -Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, reusability

In an application I'm trying to build I need a lot of `UICollectionView`s (around 10). I decided to make the `collectionView`s without the use of *Storyboards*   (i.e entirely in code) . *Storyboards* complicate things(for many collectionViews) .

Here is the code:

**I)**

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
        //Create the collection View      

    let frame =                  CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero , size: CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width , height: 50))
    let layout =                 UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
     collectionView1 =           UICollectionView(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView1.dataSource = self
    collectionView1.delegate =   self
    collectionView1.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")
    collectionView1.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    view.addSubview(collectionView1) }
```

**II)**

```
 // TheData Source and Delegate 

extension ViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource , UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{


public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

 return 5

}

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


        let cell =              collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        return cell

}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
}
 }
```

This would create one `collectionView` in a View Controller , however if I had to create ten more of these I would have to rewrite the above code 10 times .

So I tried to create a separate `MyCollectionView` class with the basic implementation needed to add a `collectionView` to a `ViewController` so that
 all I had to do in my view controller was something as simple as

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {

super.viewDidLoad()

 let shoesCollection = MYCollectionView(frame : ...)
 self.view.addSubview(shoesCollection)   

 let foodCollection = MYCollectionView(frame : ...)
 self.view.addSubview(foodCollection)

 let carCollection = MYCollectionView(frame : ...)
 self.view.addSubview(carCollection)   

 }
```

or something similar . However I was unsuccessful. 
How shall I go about this? Thanks!

Comment: Subclass ViewController that has collection view.

Comment: I could use a little more elaboration , I won't know how that'd work.

Comment: Instead of adding MYCollectionView to every view controller you should subclass ViewController. Let say one of other viewcontroller that uses same collection view you should subclass like class MySecondViewController: ViewController. Then only thing you need to change is overriding UICollectionViewDataSource and UICollectionViewDelegate to display different contents.

Comment: I'm sorry my question is a little unclear. I need to add the many  `collectionViews` into the same view controller . I would want to be able to configure each view controller separately so that it displays different stuff. But still the basic implementation would be the same for all the `collectionViews` that I add. I updated the question's last code block.

Comment: Got it. Now it depends on how your collection views appear in a view controller. If a collection view is like a row, then you probably want to create a collection view with collection view cell that has the collection view you created in it.

Comment: Have you tried an array?

Comment: @HMHero Does that mean that I will still have to specify a different case for each type of the collectionView in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` delegate method?

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ No I didn't try an array . I don't know how one could possibly help my case

Comment: Ah I think I see now...My recommendation would be to use a `UICollectionViewController` to encapsulate all the cell and layout issues and add them to a containing UIViewController that only manages where each collectionView should go.

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ thanks for the suggestion. I will try to work that one out and come back with a working solution  .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will just give you simple example although I'm not sure if this is what you wanted. Again, it totally depends on the design you are implementing but this could be one of the ideas.

The idea is

1. Create a collection view that will populate 10 collection views you want to add.
2. Create a collection view cell that has the collection view you want to repeat.
3. Feed different data(food, shoes, cars and so on) to the collection view cell (MYCollectionView).
4. Feed each data to the collection view in the cell to populate the individual data.

**ViewController**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout  {
    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical

        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.register(MYCollectionView.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: NSStringFromClass(MYCollectionView.self))
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
        return collectionView
    }()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        collectionView.frame = view.bounds
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: NSStringFromClass(MYCollectionView.self), for: indexPath) as! MYCollectionView
        return cell
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.bounds.width, height: 100)
    }
}
```

**MYViewController**

```
class MYCollectionView: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal

        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate =   self
        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        return collectionView
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        contentView.addSubview(collectionView)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        collectionView.frame = bounds
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 15
    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        return cell

    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: bounds.height, height: bounds.height)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Clicked")
    }
}
```

Updated: 
Since the question was only about reusing collection view I didn't really pass the data all the way to the reused collection views. Assuming that when the view controller is loaded you have the data, let say array of shoes, food and cars and also each array components are array too.

For example,

```
let shoes = [...] //array of shoes
let foods = [...] //array of foods
let cars = [...] //array of cars
let data = [shoes, foods, cars]
```

Now your data array has 3 components and this will decide number of the collection view you created in your question. So in the view controller in my example code,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: NSStringFromClass(MYCollectionView.self), for: indexPath) as! MYCollectionView
    let components = data[indexPath.item]
    cell.data = components
    return cell
}
```

In MYCollectionView, you should have a variable, data.

```
var data:[WhateverYourDataModel] = [] {
    didSet {
        collectionView.releadData()
    }
}

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
}

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier", for: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray

    //let component = data[indexPath.item]
    //You should create a custom collection view cell to display whatever you want to display with the data, component. 

    return cell
}
```

To make it clean, your data object should have common base model so you can pass them from view controller all the way down to the collection view in the MYCollectionView.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for providing me with the code. I am not clear with two things. 

**A** Following step 3  How would I use the above code to create , say 2 collectionViews one with 3 items and  another with 4 items.  

**B** you say in step 4 that "_Feed each data to the collection view in the cell_" , do you mean "_feed each cell in the collection View_" ?.

Comment: @Tyrone Updated my answer for clarification.

Comment: I finally get it now. Again , thanks for being helpful.

Comment: @HMHero I have brutally copied and pasted your code in a second view controller, and it compiles and run. But the horizontal scrolling isn't working. Actually I had previously adapted the code into a small project, and when a section is selected all items (cells) in it are selected. I see it from all images enlarging because they get the focus (it's on tvOS, but it shouldn't really make much difference?). Still without scrolling. Any idea?

Comment: @MicheleDall'Agata I updated the code. Basically I added more item to horizontal collection view so you can scroll and added collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath... delegate to the horizontal collection view.

Comment: @HMHero That was fast! Still not working, though. I had already raised the number of cells myself (and the size). Also I see a new print("Clicked") - that doesn't get called either. Unless it is tvOS, but all my other ports to tvOS with collection views work fine.

Comment: @MicheleDall'Agata I attached the image. I copied the code and everything works fine. Can you copy the new code and try it without adding your code?

Comment: @HMHero then it must be the focus engine in tvOS. Ok, thanks for your time!

Comment: @HMHero I have found it!!! I had to call collectionView(_:canFocusItemAt:) in the main collection view and return false. Is this way the whole nested collection (the rows) can't get focused and the focus is passed to the cells in the nested collection. All right, thanks a lot, great piece of code!

Comment: @MicheleDall'Agata Ha Ha. I was looking for that piece of code in my old tvOS project almost about to tell what you found.